# cycle in jsp can't use variable

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

On my jsp page I have:

```
<%
                            int a = 8;
                            int iter = 4;

                            for (int i =0; i <iter; i++){ %>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="con col-md-12"></div>

                                <%  for (int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) { %>
                                <%if (a>=0) {%>
                                <div class="col-md-3 marg">
                                    <h3><a href="//webdesign-master.ru" target="_blank">${products[a].description}  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" ></a></h3>

                                    <a href="//webdesign-master.ru" target="_blank"><img src= "/try/imgage/${products[a].id}" alt="alt"></a>


                                    <p>${products[a].price}</p>
                                </div>

                                <%}%>

                                <% a--; }%>

                            </div>
                        <%}%>
```

1) How to receive **a** and **iter** variables from mvc?(
  I had tried request.getParameter("a"); in jsp, and 
    model.addObject("a", a);
)

2) why products[a] give me a emty place in browser?

Products - list with enteties.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the view code and this is isolated code. You cannot access them in your servlet instance (this is what you are trying to do right?)

What you can do is to declare some variables as Model in your Controller and Pass Model to your View. This is the idea of MVC.

Comment: No, I'm pass this variables from servlet(model.addobject("a,a")). But it's second problem, why i can't iterate my list?